# Accessing console of Hyper-V guest when guest has no network configured remotely

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

Is there a way to get console access (possibly remote desktop access) to a Hyper-V guest remotely when the guest has no network connection?

I'd like to provide console access to the owner of the guest without them logging into the Hyper-V host machine.

Locally, VMConnect application does this. However, this requires login to the Hyper-V Host.

Think it as a IPMI remote console but for a Hyper-V guest.

Use case:

- Ability to have the owner of the guest to install their own OS manually and remotely.

Comment: Just open Hyper-V manager, connect to the host the vm resides and open the console?

Comment: See "I'd like to provide console access to the owner of the guest without them logging into the Hyper-V host machine."

Comment: Just use the Hyper-V manager on *another* machine then.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using Apache Guacamole.

It has ability to connect directly to Hyper-V guests' screen using VMBus.